# Length of Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript

I know this line does what it's supposed to do:

```
Data.AppointmentList[0].AppointmentList[0].OrderNo + ", ";
```

I have to export all the `OrderNo` there exist in all `AppointmentList.AppointmentList`

From this array (Not the correct one):

```
{
    "AppointmentList": [
        {
            "AppointmentList": [
                {
                    "OrderNo": 111,
                    "OrderNo": 222
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

JS:

```
$.each(Data, function(i, item){
  for(i= 0; i < Object.keys(Data.AppointmentList.AppointmentList.OrderNo).length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("divlist").innerHTML += Data.AppointmentList[0].AppointmentList[0].OrderNo + ", ";
    }
})
```

Need this output:

> 111, 222

Comment: sounds like you could use Array.reduce

Comment: Your object has some errors. It should look something like this: var AppointmentList = [{"OrderNo":111},{"OrderNo":222}];

Comment: Put everything you want to show in an array, then use `array.join(', ')` to connect them all with commas.

Comment: Why do you have two levels of `AppointmentList`?

Comment: Please show the "correct one", or at least enough of the data so that it's valid.

Comment: Don't use both `$.each` and a `for` loop. Also, don't use `Object.keys()` to count the number of elements in an array. And last but not least, when you iterate over an array you should actually use the index variable `i` for indexing, not `0`.

Comment: How do i write the line Object.keys to join those arrays?

Comment: Please show tha actual structure of the input object. You can't have two `OrderNo:` keys in the same object.

Comment: The 0 was for test.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand. Is there anyone wan't to write the code for me?

Comment: The `JSON` tag explicitly indicates that is not for JavaScript Objects, and I see no code that would indicate the use of JSON (i.e. a string representation of JavaScript Objects).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let input = {
  "AppointmentList": [
    {"AppointmentList": [{"OrderNo": 1}, {"OrderNo": 2}]},
    {"AppointmentList": [{"OrderNo": 3}]},
    {"AppointmentList": [{"OrderNo": 4}, {"OrderNo": 5}, {"OrderNo": 6}]}
  ]
};

let orders = input.AppointmentList.flatMap(a => a.AppointmentList).map(a => a.OrderNo);

console.log(orders.join(', '));
```

Comment: '{"AppointmentList":[{"Code":"10","Index":"2000","ResourceType":"1010","ResourceId":"J","ResourceName":"--","Active":true,"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","PunchIn":"07:30","PunchOut":"16:00","BreakStart1":"09:00","BreakEnd1":"09:15","BreakStart2":"11:30","BreakEnd2":"12:00","BreakStart3":"14:00","BreakEnd3":"14:15","AppointmentList":[{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","StartTime":"06:45","EndTime":"07:45","OrderNo":19283},{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","StartTime":"07:45","EndTime":"15:30","OrderNo":19246},{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","StartTime":"15:30","EndTime":"16:30","OrderNo":0}],'

Comment: Some of the array

Comment: ###This output the correct :-)###
How do I handle it foreach OrderNo?

Comment: @ThomasFrickeTrampedach use `orders.forEach(order => { // do something with order })` ?

Comment: Thanks, Thats just perfect:D